# Best practice for writing to multiple files at different frequency?

Tags: c++, file-io, ofstream

Looking for the best approach to manage file output in a system (C++). Thanks in advance for any reply!

The system:

- Runs non-stop for weeks
- Only information at certain seconds need to be written to files (can't be predetermined until the end of the second)
- One log/debug type of file will be written at higher frequency (say every 1-60 seconds) and in larger chunks (0.1-0.5k each time, could potentially be several k per minute)
- One summary type of file will be written at lower frequency (say every 5-30 min) and in smaller chunks (one short line)

My thoughts:

- Have two ofstreams, one for each file

  - Question 1: Is it any better to use just one ofstream and switch file attribute when necessary?
- Create two std::strings to store potential information for each second. Then at the end of the second, if info needs to be written to one or more of the files, open the file(s), write, and close.

  - Question 2: Is string a good holder? Is there some sort of buffer that I can write without flush, then at the end of the second I just decide whether to discard or flush?
  - Question 3: Given the larger file may be written as frequent as every second, do we open/close every second? Is it better to keep it open all the time?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: 1. I would have a separate ofstream per file. However, I don't know whether you should close and reopen them or keep them always open. 2. string or stringstream are good. They are in memory so you can do with them as you please.

Comment: Do you need to read from this files while system is working? If no, I would keep files open while system is working.

Comment: I do not need to read from either files. both write-only.

Comment: 1) Yes, 2 ofstreams please ! 2) String is a good holder, but if the system works non-stop, it seems interesting to write on the flow,  keeping in mind that strings and unflushed io vanishes with a power cut. 3) Keep it open.  Or write several smaller log files (like some database servers do) with a sequential numbering scheme in their name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Answer 1: use separate ofstream (one per file).
- Answer 2: You can use ostringstream to store partial information.
- Answer 3: You can keep the file open only if you don't need to read from it. Anyway open/close every second is not so much expensive

Comment: If I keep the files open, do I need to use std::endl every so often (to flush the output)? If so how often?